# What is the type of the delete async method in typeorm?

Tags: javascript, async-await, nestjs, typeorm

```
async deleteMultiple (
    userId: number,
    items: number[],
  ): Promise<DeleteResult> {
    const result = await this._sampleRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .from(SampleEntity)
      .where('id IN (:...id)', { id: items })
      .execute();

    if (result.affected) {
      await this._sampleChangesService.create(
        userId,
        SampleDataTypes.SAMPLE_CONSTANT,
        [changeActions.DELETE],
      );
    }

    return result;
  }
```

What is the type of the async method?
Does it Promise or something else?

NOTE: Delete action return this object

```
 { raw: [], affected: 2 }
```

The value for affected can be different depending on deleted items. It can be 0 if nothing deleted, or other numbers if deleted 1 or more.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow. You have types set up right? Are they incorrect and you need to know what the correct type should be, or is something else going on?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I am not sure does it correct or not.

Comment: `async` functions always return promises

Answer (score -1):

For this question using Promise is the correct way.